# Getting distance from Google Maps from a series of stops using ColdFusion

Tags: php, google-maps, coldfusion

My client makes deliveries and needs to record the mileage driven between each stop as well as a total miles for the day.  The route is known ahead of time.  The addresses are also known so I am able to obtain the lat/long of the addresses for Google maps.  I'd like to get the distance for each leg and record them in the database for end of year reporting as well as a grand total of miles driven for the year (the grand total is the easy part so that doesn't really need to be addressed).

1)  Is this possible with the current Google Maps API?  I have the Google map key.
2)  If yes, do you have a link to a demo that I can look at?

I'm coding this in ColdFusion but would be open to reverse engineering a PHP page.

Comment: What are the parts that you are able to do?  Also, before you get to hooked into latitudes and longitudes, bear in mind that you probably want driving distances, not straight line distances.

Comment: I'm not tied into lat/long, just stating that I can collect that data from a dropped pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, you have to request the [directionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). The service-response will contain the distance for each step([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON)), you only need to fetch the desired data out of the response.

Note: you may only request routes with up to 8 waypoints, when your routes include more waypoints you must split the routes.

Comment: That example link is perfect!  I'm sure this is the answer I need but let me do my due diligence before I mark this as correct.

Comment: In addition to the link you provided, there is also a section for the Google Distance Matrix API which will allow me to calculate the distances without weeding through the driving directions.  I just wanted to share that link as well:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/